# Convert unsigned int to signed int through google BigQuery

Tags: sql, int, google-bigquery, uint

I tried to run a query on google BigQuery api and got an exception as follows:

> "Argument type mismatch in function IF: 'distinctPlayers' is type 'TYPE_UINT64', '0' is type 'TYPE_INT32'."

The query is too big so I wrote only part of it where it fails.

> QUERY : sum(if(action_type == 3, distinctPlayers, 0)) as  Game_Viral_Acceptor_Count

What I understood is:

```
if condition is true 
then set distinctPlayers of type unsigned int64 
otherwise set 0 which is of type int32
```

Can anyone throw some light on how to convert `unsigned int64` to `signed int` through `BigQuery`.

Thanks in advance,
Omkar

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the way you cast to signed int is via the `INTEGER` function. So you should be able to successfully run

```
... SUM(IF(action_type == 3, INTEGER(distinctPlayers), 0)) AS ...
```

However, the message you're seeing actually points to a bug in BigQuery -- I'm filing the bug internally right now.

Comment: It seems like the bug is still there, I had the same error today. 
I had to do this to make it work:
INTEGER(count (distinct myField, 10000))