# BigQuery COALESCE/IFNULL type mismatch with literals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In SQL I usually use `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` to ensure that I get numbers and not `NULL` when my queries contain aggregate functions like `COUNT` and `SUM`, for example:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(foo), 0) AS foo_count FROM …
```

However, in BigQuery I run into an error:

> Argument type mismatch in function IFNULL: 'f0_' is type uint64, '0' is type int32.

Is there a way to make BigQuery understand that a literal 0 should be interpreted as a `unit64` in this context?

I've tried using `CAST`, but there's no `unit64` type I can cast to, so I try `INTEGER`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(foo), CAST(0 AS INTEGER)) AS foo_count FROM …
```

That gives me basically the same error, but at least I've successfully gotten a 64-bit zero instead of a 32-bit:

> Argument type mismatch in function IFNULL: 'f0_' is type uint64, '0' is type int64.

The same happens if I use `INTEGER(0)`.

I can get it to work if I cast both arguments to `INTEGER`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(INTEGER(COUNT(foo)), INTEGER(0)) AS foo_count FROM …
```

But now it starts to be verbose. Is this really how you're supposed to do it in BigQuery?

Comment: You should only need the `INTEGER` around your `COUNT`, correct? Still not ideal as an implicit conversion should be easy enough for the engine, but so it goes... BTW, this might cast some light as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059778/convert-unsigned-int-to-signed-int-through-google-bigquery

Comment: True, don't know why I didn't consider that, but should still be unnecessary. Thanks for the link – seems like the bug hasn't been fixed in a while :)

Comment: These bug reports seems relevant (1) https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=121 , (2) https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=375

Comment: @KinaanKhanSherwani thanks, I'll have to keep an eye out for the fixes mentioned in those reports.

Comment: I've added an answer along with @Kinaan's link so that people searching for this in the future should be able to find an answer quickly instead of rooting through comments.

Comment: In which case will `COUNT` return a NULL instead of 0?

Comment: @dnoeth good point. The application that generates the SQL wraps aggregate functions like this since many of them can return null, it doesn’t make an exception for `COUNT` beacause it would just complicate things. I should probably have used `SUM` as an example but I didn’t think of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in BigQuery which has been around for quite some time. For the time being you need to force the conversion of the `COUNT`, but you shouldn't need to do it for your "0".

The following should work:

```
SELECT IFNULL(INTEGER(COUNT(foo)), 0) AS foo_count FROM
```

Thanks @Kinaan Khan Sherwani for the link to the [official bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=121).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to cast both as BIGINT instead, 2.1 billion is not a large number considering BigQuery/BigData?

Comment: I don't believe that Bigquery has a "BIGINT" data type. Just the 64-bit INTEGER. I don't work with it very much, so I could be mistaken, but I believe that the original poster found the same thing.